# How to correct Failed global > initialization: FileNotOpen

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run eos and using the std docs - https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/build-validation

I am trying - ~/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod -f ~/opt/mongodb/mongod.conf and I get the following -

> trevor@ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-lon1-01:~/opt/mongodb$
>   2018-08-03T13:03:01.096+0000 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global
>   initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open
>   "/home/trevor/opt/mongodb/log/mongodb.log"
>   ~/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod -f ~/opt/mongodb/mongod.conf

I tried already chmod 755 on the log and checking the conf as per other posts here. Nothing worked. Here is the conf -

```
trevor@ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-lon1-01:~/opt/mongodb$ more *conf
systemLog:
 destination: file
 path: /home/trevor/opt/mongodb/log/mongodb.log
 logAppend: true
 logRotate: reopen
net:
 bindIp: 127.0.0.1,::1
 ipv6: true
storage:
 dbPath: /home/trevor/opt/mongodb/data
```

I have Ubuntu 18.04.

Any idea what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Run as sudo. That worked for me.

> trevor@ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-lon1-01:~/opt$ sudo ~/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod
>   -f ~/opt/mongodb/mongod.conf & [1] 23948
>    trevor@ubuntu-s-4vcpu-8gb-lon1-01:~/opt$